# Dynamic Choice Field

Tags: workflow, choice-field

I have a questions about choice fields. I am using a content control combo box in a word document which users fill out depending on a document topic. I would like to be able to easily manage that choice list, so instead of using the text box in the Column Settings to change the choices, I'd like to use a list that is already managed.
Is this possible?

Comment: Is using a Lookup Column an option?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is a data connection. If you are editing the form with infopath you can retrieve the information from a field in antother and use them as values in a control for example a dropdown. Check this [Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-a-drop-down-list-box-e5cf2494-7a35-48f9-8d9e-3390dd23c888)